# Tivoli Directory Server Password Response Control sends a 655618 Error Code

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, tivoli, password-policy

I have configured a password policy in Tivoli Directory Server and enabled 'User must change password after reset'.  I am changing the user password through admin login, try to login through the user, and then reading the password policy response (through java code).  I keep getting error code 655618 (outOfBounds) and warning code 2 (none).

Could anyone please let me know where I might be going wrong?